# How to derive $0,0,1,0,1,0,2,1,0,2,1,0,3,... = \lfloor(1/4)\lceil\sqrt{4n}\rceil^2\rfloor- n$ (A216607)

Tags: sequences-and-series, integers

[A216607](https://oeis.org/A216607) ("The sequence used to represent partition binary diagram as an array."), `floor((1/4)*ceil(sqrt(4*n))^2) - n` (LaTeX see below).

0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2, 1 ,0, 3, 2, 1, 0,... is statified by $
\newcommand\floor[1]{\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor}
\newcommand\ceil[1]{\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil}
\floor{\dfrac{\ceil{\sqrt{4n}}^2}{4}}-n
$

How can I derive this law of construction?

Or notated in groups
$
\newcommand\floor[1]{\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor}
\newcommand\ceil[1]{\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil}
\floor{\dfrac{\ceil{\sqrt{4n}}^2}{4}}-n
~:~ \left\lbrace\begin{array}{l}
0,  \\
0,1,  \\
0,1, \\
0,2,1, \\
0,2,1, \\
0,3,2,1, \\
0,3,2,1, \\
0,... \\
\end{array}\right.
$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [OEIS sequence A216607](https://oeis.org/A216607) entry has
as the second formula line: $\,a(n^2) = a(n^2+n) = 0.\,$
Define the sequence $\,q(n):=\lfloor n^2/4\rfloor\,$
which alternates $\,n^2\,$ with $\,n^2+n\,$ and is
[OEIS sequence A002620](https://oeis.org/A002620) "Quarter-squares". The
significance of this is clear from the table:

```
  n    | 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
-------+--+--+-----+-----+--------+--------+-----------+-----------+
 a(n)  | 0| 0| 1  0| 1  0| 2  1  0| 2  1  0| 3  2  1  0| 3  2  1  0|
n+a(n) | 1| 2| 4  4| 6  6| 9  9  9|12 12 12|16 16 16 16|20 20 20 20|
 b(n)  | 2| 3| 4  4| 5  5| 6  6  6| 7  7  7| 8  8  8  8| 9  9  9  9|
```

where $\,b(n):=\lceil 2\sqrt{n}\rceil\,$ is
[OEIS sequence A027434](https://oeis.org/A027434) which is an inverse function of $\,q(n).\,$
Thus $\,n=b(q(n)),\,n+a(n)=q(b(n))\,$ and this implies that $\,a(n)=q(b(n))-n.$